# Can AWS S3 files in buckets get deleted by a download timing out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A few AWS S3 files might have gotten deleted while trying to download everything for a local backup. The download/connection timed-out a couple times. The next day several HTML/JS files are missing but the folder structures are intake. Is this even possible or could this have been caused by the timed-out connection?

Comment: Did you ask Amazon? Doubt you'lll get a better answer here than you would from them.

Comment: Files being deleted through no fault of the user is not something Amazon would freely admit. I am curious if anyone else has come across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable logging and versioning? Those are two places I would check first. Is it possible that you or your application could have deleted the files?

> Is this even possible or could this have been caused by the timed-out
>   connection?

The two are not likely connected. I've never heard of a connection time out causing files to be deleted. You should consult with AWS, they may be able to give your more information about your specific files.

## The likelyhood that Amazon lost files?

Low. (Still in the realm of possibility but low).

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Amazon S3’s standard storage is:

- Backed with the Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement.
- Designed for 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of objects over a given year.
- Designed to sustain the concurrent loss of data in two facilities.